# Python 3 Django 3.0 Running but not listening or opening port

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am using PyCharm and an instance running in AWS for remote debugging.  When I start debugging the server starts and continues to run.  However, it is inaccessable and doesn't appear to be grabbing the port.  Running with sudo doesn't change anything.   When running the app using gunicorn it works perfectly.

**Pycharm Console**

```
ssh://ubuntu@34.204.XXX.X:22/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/ubuntu/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 0.0.0.0 --port 46691 --file /opt/ctp/cloudportal/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
pydev debugger: process 3021 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.5233.109)
[2019-12-14 03:51:18] 3028 INFO django.utils.autoreload:run_with_reloader:598 - Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py:28: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if sys.version_info[0] is 2 and  sys.version_info[1] is 1:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py:28: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if sys.version_info[0] is 2 and  sys.version_info[1] is 1:
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 14, 2019 - 03:51:19
Django version 3.0, using settings 'CloudPortal.settings_dev'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

**Linux Server**

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-128-120:~$ sudo ps -alf
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S ubuntu    3028  3021  3  80   0 - 72808 poll_s 03:51 pts/0    00:00:09 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ctp/cloudportal/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
4 S root      3139  3116  0  80   0 - 17077 poll_s 03:56 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo ps -alf
4 R root      3140  3139  0  80   0 - 10023 -      03:56 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -alf
ubuntu@ip-192-168-128-120:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34753         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3002/sshd: ubuntu@p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46691         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3002/sshd: ubuntu@p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3002/sshd: ubuntu@p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      678/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      850/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:34753               :::*                    LISTEN      3002/sshd: ubuntu@p
tcp6       0      0 ::1:46691               :::*                    LISTEN      3002/sshd: ubuntu@p
tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      867/dockerd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:63342               :::*                    LISTEN      3002/sshd: ubuntu@p
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      850/sshd
```